# Javascript not loaded using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to the problem so maybe I'm making some big mistake but why my javascript external file isn't loaded by Selenium web driver? It works on the browser

Here my code `addname.html`:

```
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/lists.js' %}"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      window.onpageshow = function() {
        select_language(
          {{ language_selected|safe }}
        );
      };
    </script>
  </body>
```

my `lists.js`:

```
function select_language(language_selected) {
    if (language_selected) {
        document.getElementById('id_language').selectedIndex = language_selected
    }
}
```

my `test.py`:

```
class NewVisitorTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    [...]

    def test_can_add_name_and_read_it_after(self):
        # Bob go to the homepage
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/')
        breakpoint()
```

the web console of the browser (firefox) gives (in yellow):

```
The script from “http://localhost:61234/static/js/lists.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:61234/static/js/lists.js”.
```

and later when the page uses the select_language function it is undefinied. Ask for more code if you need.

Thank you

Comment: That message means the web server isn't sending proper headers.

Comment: Thank you, and what can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: You could switch to a different web server like Apache or Nginx

Comment: But for now I'm working on my machine so, If I'm not wrong, I'm using only the django server (manage.py runserver)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about that but it sounds like the django dev server is a piece of junk.